# How do you duplicate two matched lines in order with sed?

Tags: sed

If I have a file that looks like this:

```
word
foo
bar
word
```

And I want to duplicate `foo\nbar` lines, so that it looks like this:

```
word
foo
bar
foo
bar
word
```

I have tried using `N` to load the next line into the buffer, but I must be using it incorrectly, as it appears to skip over lines sometimes.

```
sed -e '{
N
s/\(foo\nbar\)/\1\1/
}' foobar.txt
```

I think it is loading `word\nfoo` into the buffer, then `bar\nword` into the buffer, and misses the pattern entirely.  How do you use `N` appropriately?  Would this be easier with awk, perl, or some other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specifically tagged the question with sed I thought I'd post a sed solution:

```
/foo/,/bar/{
i\
foo
i\
bar
d
}


$ sed -f s.sed input 
word
foo
bar
foo
bar
word
```

Answer (score 1):

in awk:

```
awk -v word1="foo" -v word2="bar" '
  {print} 
  prev==word1 && $1==word2 {print word1; print word2}
  {prev=$1}
' filename
```